# Python list not picking up min and max values correctly

Tags: python, list

I am very new to programming and do it mainly as a hobby to de-stress from work, I have just started having a go at python and I am trying to find the range of X amount of numbers.

the program works, but instead of the minimum & maximum values being returned, it is using the final 2 values of the list.

As I said, I do this as a hobby and don't have a huge amount of experience, but I have no doubt it is something simple but am struggling to understand why it isn't taking the values it should.

```
numSales = int(input("How many numbers are you entering? "))
# creates a variable for number of numbers, allowing the list to be of length determined by the user

noNumbers = []
# creates list called noNumbers

maxListLength = numSales
# gives the maximum length of the list called dailySales
while len(noNumbers) < maxListLength:
    item = input("Enter a number to add to the list: ")
    noNumbers.append(item)

# Asks for an input as long as the number of variables in dailySales is less than the value of maxListLength
print(noNumbers)

lowest = int(min(noNumbers))
# returns the lowest value of dailySales
print(lowest)

highest = int(max(noNumbers))
# returns the largest value of dailySales
print(highest)

numRange = int(highest - lowest)
# need to subtract highest from lowest to print the sales range

print(numRange)
```

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your calls to `min` and `max` are comparing strings, not numbers. Store numbers in your list: `noNumbers.append(int(item))`.

Comment: @chepner has the right answer, but also worth mentionning, please, in the future, put your comments above your statements not below.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @chepner That's a valid concern, but `min` and `max` work the way you'd expect even if the values are string-numbers.

Comment: @Nearoo you keep repeating this assertion but you are incorrect, string numbers are sorted lexically - not numerically, i.e. `max('2', '10') == '2'`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. ... @AChampion - `lexicographically`

Comment: @wwii yes, but that is too long :) and wiki says AKA [`lexical order`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert ints in the list instead of strings, just modify:

```
item = input("Enter a number to add to the list: ")
noNumbers.append(item)
```

By:

```
item = int(input("Enter a number to add to the list: "))
noNumbers.append(item)
```

Comment: Wrong. Python sorts numbers that are `string` the way you'd intuitively expect. It shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: "10" < "2" equals True in python.

Comment: @Nearoo you are incorrect lexical ordering is not the same as numerical ordering.

Comment: @GabrielBenCompte You're right, weird! But try `min` and `max` on a list containing string-numbers. It will spit out the right value.

Comment: @Nearoo, try `max(['2', '10'])` what do you get?

Comment: Another time min(["10", "2", "7", "4"]) = "10". When ordered lexical only the firsts numbers are compared (unless they are equal). That's why "10000000" < "2", because "1"<"2"

Comment: @AChampion Damn.  I tried ["1", "2"] as well as ["0", "1", ... "99"], both are correct. But that was only a coincidence. You guys are right. Sorry. Thanks Gabriel, I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, I tested it on a repl.it and it did min max just fine. You might want to make the `item` an int, it makes the subsequent `int()` calls unnecessary:

https://repl.it/repls/ChubbyAlienatedModulus

```
numSales = int(input("How many numbers are you entering? "))
# creates a variable for number of numbers, allowing the list to be of length determined by the user

noNumbers = []
# creates list called noNumbers

maxListLength = numSales
# gives the maximum length of the list called dailySales
while len(noNumbers) < maxListLength:
    item = int(input("Enter a number to add to the list: "))
    noNumbers.append(item)

# Asks for an input as long as the number of variables in dailySales is less than the value of maxListLength
print(noNumbers)

lowest = min(noNumbers)
# returns the lowest value of dailySales
print(lowest)

highest = max(noNumbers)
# returns the largest value of dailySales
print(highest)

numRange = highest - lowest
# need to subtract highest from lowest to print the sales range

print(numRange)
```

Comment: The subsequent `int()` calls are now unnecessary!

Comment: Oh okay, should i remove then

Comment: It's also incorrect. Python sorts numbers that are `string` the way you'd intuitively expect.

Comment: @SheshankS. Let me rephrase. `min` and `max` return the expected value even if all values are `str`. Try it yourself.